# Preventing DOM redraw of items that don't get filltered out when a collection is filtered in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm implementing filtering in an Ember application. Each item is pretty chunky though, so I want to draw them as few times as possible.

When I use the filter function on the collection like below:

```
filteredContent: function() {
    return this.get('content').filter(function (item){
        if (this.get('filter') == "all") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return item.type == 2;
        }
    }, this);
}.property('content.@each', 'filter')
```

then it seems to destroy every element and redraw the new set, instead of just destroying the ones that are filtered out.

Given the following model:

```
model: function () {
    return [{
        firstName: 'Kris',
        lastName: 'Selden',
        type: 1
    }, {
        firstName: 'Luke',
        lastName: 'Melia',
        type: 2
    }, {
        firstName: 'Formerly Alex',
        lastName: 'Matchneer',
        type: 2
    }];
}
```

if I set filter to 2, I expect "Kris" to be destroyed and the other two to stay. Instead, all three are destroyed and Luke and Alex are recreated.

console.log of willDestroy / didInsert when filtering by 2:

> ```
> destroyed element Kris
> destroyed element Luke  
> destroyed element Formerly Alex
> inserted element Luke
> inserted element Formerly Alex
> ```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do it without the expensive destroy/recreate?

Included Bin is logging on create and destroy of elements.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iNUBOCI/2/edit